# Jest Testing React Component TypeError: Mutation is not a function

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

Using Jest testing for react component.
I want to test for a mutation in the post.
The mutation is triggered by a button onclick event.
Therefore I've called the function with mutation inside it.
It works in the website but when I'm writing the unit test for that component using Jest, it's not working.
I've taken reference from this -
https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/6452

Getting the error

TypeError: xMutation is not a function

```
  178 |     onResumeState = () => {
  179 |         const { xMutation } = this.props;
> 180 |         xMutation().then(({ data }) => {
      |         ^
  181 |             const { x: { success } } = data;
  182 |             if (success) {
  183 |                 this.setState({ playState: true });
```

**x.query.js**

```
export const xMutation = gql`
    mutation xMutation($xId: String!) {
        y(xId: $xId){
        ...on SuccessActionResponse {
            z{
            id
            }
            message
            success
        }
        ...on ErrorResponse{
            message
            success
        }
        }
    }
`;

export const xMutationParams = {
    options: props => (
        {
            variables: {
                xId: props.xId,
            },
            refetchQueries: () => [{
                query: getxQuery,
                fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
                variables: {
                    id: props.xId,
                },
            }],
        }
    ),
    name: 'xMutation',
};
```

**x.test.js**

```
const mocks = [
    {
        request: {
            query: xMutation,
            fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
            variables: { xId: 'eb1bcc5c-9f17-409c-8b23-356c5523b5f0' },
        },
        result: {
            data: {
                xData: {
                    id: 2,
                    yId: 2,
                },
                message: 'Resumed Successfully',
                success: true,
            },
        },
    },
];

describe('X component', () => {
    const { headerData } = defaultProps;
    render(
        <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
            <StatusTab {...headerData} />
        </MockedProvider>,
    );

    test('should render pause/play state', async () => {
            const linkText = 'yyy';
            expect(screen.getByText(`(${linkText})`)).toBeInTheDocument();
            // await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
            await act(async () => {
                fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(`(${linkText})`));
            });
        }
    });
});
```

**x.jsx**

```
onResumeState = () => {
        const { xMutation } = this.props;
        xMutation().then(({ data }) => {
            const { x: { success } } = data;
            if (success) {
                this.setState({ playState: true });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Graphql queries can be transpiled by a webpack plugin to skip parsing and compiling during runtime. It looks like your test lacks the necessary preprocessing. Try using `useQuery` instead of `().then`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm new to this and therefore messed this up. I didn't need to use Mocked Provider for this. Was able to work with just a mock function.
Here's the updated x.test.jsx which works-

```
const defaultProps = {
    headerData: {
        ..., // Different props
        // Added mock function
        xMutation: jest.fn().mockImplementation(
            () => Promise.resolve({ data: { xAssignment: { success: true } } }),
        ),
    },
};

describe('StatusTab component', () => {
    const { headerData } = defaultProps;
    render(<StatusTab {...headerData} />);

    test('should render pause/play state', async () => {
        expect(screen.getByText(`(${resumeText})`)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByLabelText(`${xText}`)).toBeDisabled();
        await act(async () => {
            fireEvent.click(screen.getByText(`(${resumeText})`));
        });
        expect(screen.getByText(`(${pausedText})`)).toBeInTheDocument();
        expect(screen.getByLabelText(`${xText}`)).not.toBeDisabled();
    });
});
```

If you're looking to use graphql apollo mutations in jest, this is a good reference - https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/development-testing/testing/